# Is there a way we can manipulate a header value received from an upstream server in an ingress resource?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have following urls pointing to an Ingress resource:

```
https://example.com/USA/my-app
https://example.com/UK/my-app
```

I have written an ingress configurations to target different services based up the country in URI:

```
host: example.com
    path: /USA(/|$)(.*)$  # Application context of upstream server is /my-app 
    backend:
      serviceName: USA-REGION-SERVICE
      servicePort: 80
    path: /UK(/|$)(.*)$  # Application context of upstream server is /my-app
    backend:
      serviceName: UK-REGION-SERVICE
      servicePort: 80
```

And, I rewrite the target using ingress annotation as:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
```

The problem I am face here is with JSESSIONID cookie; the upstream servers returning the set-cookie header with path /my-app which is right; however browser points to paths /USA/my-app or /UK/my-app.

As, a result I loose the session generated and returned by upstream servers as set-cookie header and users log out soon they send another request.

Is there any way I can update JSESSIONID response header? Or, there is problem with the way I am trying it?

Comment: Have you used affinity: cookie annotation?

Comment: No, I have not used. The problem here is the cookie path set by upstream servers.

Comment: I would suggest you add the annotation https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#session-affinity

Comment: I think session affinity wont work here as the problem is with the JSESSIONID cookie path.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-path` [annotation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/affinity/cookie#sticky-sessions) should solve your problem.

> **Name:** `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-path`
>
> **Description:** Path that will be set on the cookie (required if your Ingress paths use regular expressions)
>
> **Value:** string (defaults to the currently matched path)